# How to handle umlauts in a MySQL `WHERE` clause?

Tags: mysql, unicode

My Table collation is `utf8_general_ci` and character set is `utf8`. If I run a query like the following, it does not show me any value.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield = "BjÃ¶rn Borg"
OR myfield = "FrüFrü & Tigerlily";
```

So how I can fetch the values from table ?

Comment: Are you really running the query including the semi-colons?

Comment: @ Jan Zyka: yes,I am running query using semi-colons

Comment: amazing spiderman ... :) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html (you don't use semicolon in this way)

Comment: "Ã¶" Is the UTF-8 for 'ö' interpreted as ISO 8859-1 or CP1252. Why does your command contain this? Why aren't you just using `WHERE myfield = "Björn Borg"`? Does your browser or whatever other software you're using not support UTF-8 well? Did someone literally put a mangled string in your database that you're searching for? I notice `FrüFrü` appears in your post so its really hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @bames actually this both strings are in database and I have to search the all records having this name and when I run this select statement ti dose not show any record but this record are there in database , but i am using SET NAMES 'utf8' then it is working fine for field FrüFrü but it is not working for string BjÃ¶rn Borg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be in your connection charset. Try to run

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'
```

And then your query.

Comment: @Ashish Which tools/script do you use to browse the result set?

Comment: @Ashish Was your table created as utf8/utf8_general_ci or you converted it to utf8 from some other encoding?

Comment: Actually I am working on local copy of an table and character set is utf8 and collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: @Ashish The most likely your umlauts have been inserted/converted improperly. And their internal representation is improper. Try to select the rows with umlauts by the primary key and check if the characters are good utf-8 characters.

Comment: sorry but how can I check the characters are good utf-8 characters.

Comment: @Ashish if you see something like Ã¶ instead of umlauts that means you have a charset problem. Don't forget to set names to utf-8

Comment: sorry but how can I set Names to utf8.

Comment: @Ashish run query: SET NAMES 'utf8'

Comment: I have tried it is working with myfield = "FrüFrü & Tigerlily"; but it is not working for  myfield = "BjÃ¶rn Borg"

Comment: actually I am using this where clause in stored procedure so can I use this SET NAMES 'utf8' in stored procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

There are more places where MySQL defines character sets, including at the column level.

To check the database settings:
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';

To check the table settings: SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;

To check the individual columns: SHOW FULL COLUMNS IN tablename;

If you created a database with the wrong encoding, you will have to change every single occurence of a bad charset in all of these.

Comment: I got solution it is working with SET NAMES 'utf8' but it is working only for myfield = "FrüFrü & Tigerlily" but it is not working for myfield = "BjÃ¶rn Borg" so what i have to do for that and how can i use this in my stored procedure ?